# Scope of Global Table in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am using VS 2010. I have created a solution in SSIS containing 18 packages in it.

My question is if I create a Global table in one package (for example: Package A) and after running that package, what would be the scope of that table?

Can I use that same Global table in another package (let's say in Package B) or is there any other way of using the global table in other package?

Comment: I assume by "global table" you mean a global temp table? A global temp table will be dropped when there are no connections using it. This would mean that unless PackageB has already started your global temp table will be dropped at the end of execution of PackageA. Maybe you need to rethink a global table and use a persistent table instead.

Comment: @SeanLange Can you explain me how persistent table would me? How an I use them in ssis?

Comment: A persistent table is one that is always in your database....the typical tables you use in queries.

Comment: Why would you use a global temporary table instead of just ... a table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, I am working on a db in which I dont have rights to do that!!

Comment: @SeanLange Can you help me out on how to create persistance table in ssis?

Comment: You can't create a permanent table even in tempdb? Did you even try?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Even I have gone for that, but no rights! So is there anything else could I try?

Comment: You could try not having two packages, I guess. If the goal of one package is to store data so that a different package can read it, then perhaps you should ask for the permissions to create a table to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Create a permanent table in a database using an `Execute SQL Task` component. In other packages store the table name in a variable and use it as Table name in your `OLEDB Source` component or Use it in **expressions** for other components

[image]

Comment: Well, I called the all other package from that package with the help of `Execute Package Task` and that runs itself in the scope of global table :)

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. Happy to help